# How to do INNER JOIN correctly ? mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables :

### table1 :

## businessId | businessName | categoryId

```
   1              name1        355
   2              name2        451
   .                .           .    
   .                .           .
```

### table2 :

## categoryId | bussinessId

```
56            2
99            2 
100           8
 .            .    
 .            .
```

so the business could be belongs to several categories (one to many relationship).

I want to get the business name by the categoryId.
I am using this query :

```
SELECT table1.businessName FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2
WHERE
table2.businessId = table1.businessId AND table2.categoryId = $_GET['categoryId'];
```

this query just get the business whose belong to specific categoryId according to tabel2 but ignore the relation at table1.

How could I improve the query to check also the relation between the categoryId and the business at table1 ?

I know that categoryId col at table1 should be immigrate to table2 , but now I could not do this ?

actually I tried also this query :

```
SELECT table1.businessName FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2
WHERE
(table2.businessId = table1.businessId AND tabl2.categoryId = $_GET['categoryId'])
OR table1.businessId = $_GET['categoryId' ;
```

but this doesn't work good! it brings many rows !

Comment: It seems you mean many-to-many. Else a category can have only one business. Why is there categoryId in table1?

Comment: 1) you're missing `on` statement; 2) if you have this type of tables then make a view where you join the info from all your table related into database; 3) I'm gonna say for this type of job you will better use a stored procedure (avoid mysql injectio[get statement])

Comment: @marek no it is not many to many ! this is mistake on the design ! (I separate the relation ), so businessId at table1 is a primaryKey ! I can't change the design now ! " know that categoryId col at table1 should be immigrate to table2 , but now I could not do this ?

"

Comment: @user3648409 "business could be belongs to several categories" + 1toM relationship => category can have only one business. That doesn't make it a category then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(untested) This query also show you data of the relationship of a `categoryId` with a `businessId` in `table1`. 
I've chosen for a `UNION` because I assumed it could be possible that in `table1` a link between category and a business is made which 
isn't included in `table2`

```
select businessName
from table1
where categoryId = $_GET['categoryId']
UNION ALL
select t1.businessName
from table1 as t1
inner join table2 as t2 on t2.categoryId = t1.categoryId AND
               t2.businessId = t1.businessId
where t2.categoryId = $_GET['categoryId']
```

Answer (score 2):

It's usually neater to have the join condition in the `on` clause. If you have multiple join conditions (business and category IDs), you can just use `and` to have them both:

```
SELECT     table1.businessName 
FROM       table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t2.businessId = t1.businessId AND 
                           t2.categoryId = t1.categoryId
WHERE      t2.categoryId = $_GET['categoryId'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try as below , so first join the tables with the common key and then filter out the data using the `where`

```
SELECT 
table1.businessName FROM table1 
INNER JOIN table2 on table2.businessId = table1.businessId
where 
table2.categoryId = $_GET['categoryId'] ;
```